# I18n in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, properties, struts2, resourcebundle

I'm new in struts2 and I want to add i18n in my web application. I sea in documentation such code:

```
<s:url id="localeEN" namespace="/" action="locale">
    <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url id="localeruRU" namespace="/" action="locale">
    <s:param name="request_locale">ru_RU</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{localeEN}">English</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localeruRU}">Russian</s:a>
```

and we need to add action class like this:

```
public class LocalizationAction extends ActionSupport {
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

and in struts.xml we add this:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="locale" class="by.bulgak.newsmanager.action.LocalizationAction">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

also I have property files with names `global` and `global_ru_RU`

I do everything that I read from tutorial but when I set param in my jsp page my IDE tells me that the name `request_locale` is unknown property..

please tell me where is my mistake.

[image]

my IDE don't sea it and thats why when I want to change language when I run my app my IDE don't call I18n methods in struts2

Comment: is it working or not as if i read your question it saying only about warning, can you describe what exact is the issue?

Comment: No it's not work, because it is not detect property request_locale. May be I didn't add some libruary? or this property is stored in struts2-core?

Comment: *I set param in my jsp page my IDE tells me that the name request_locale is unknown property..* Is a warning from the IDE? Just a silly question, have you put `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` at the top of your jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Struts2 doesn't associate default i18n property with english language.

When I set default property like this: `property_name_en.properties` it working fine.

But I don't understand why it is so.
I see many examples and I even start them into my machine and they work fine,
but my didn't work.. May be someone know what is problem?